# Applying Australia Tourist Visa from Bangkok, for Nepali

Tags: visas, australia, thailand, tourist-visas, nepali-citizens

I am Nepali citizen working/living in Thailand, can I apply for Australia tourist visa from Bangkok?

I plan to go for 2 weeks visit in april 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can apply for the Visa while in Bangkok.

[The DIPB website](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-) explains the process, which will require completing the forms and submitting via post/courier, or in person through the agent [VFS Global](http://www.border.gov.au/about/contact/offices-locations/thailand).

Do not make the mistake of assuming you can get one of the free visas. Nepal is not recognised under [that program](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-).